Odoo-Adding an approval workflow to an Odoo payment registered from a wizard throught an purchase invoice
I want to implement an payment process when the cashier try to register a payment from a purchase invoice for that I have implemented an approbation process for in the payment module excepting if the payment is initiated it will go through that process

But i have notice that Odoo creates a Transient Model  called "account.payment.register " to handle all the process of the completion of that payment being registered, it just create a payment and posted it on the same time
here is the odoo code that handle that
    def _init_payments(self, to_process, edit_mode=False):
        """ Create the payments.

        :param to_process:  A list of python dictionary, one for each payment to create, containing:
                            * create_vals:  The values used for the 'create' method.
                            * to_reconcile: The journal items to perform the reconciliation.
                            * batch:        A python dict containing everything you want about the source journal items
                                            to which a payment will be created (see '_get_batches').
        :param edit_mode:   Is the wizard in edition mode.
        """

        payments = self.env['account.payment']\
            .with_context(skip_invoice_sync=True)\
            .create([x['create_vals'] for x in to_process])

        for payment, vals in zip(payments, to_process):
            vals['payment'] = payment

            # If payments are made using a currency different than the source one, ensure the balance match exactly in
            # order to fully paid the source journal items.
            # For example, suppose a new currency B having a rate 100:1 regarding the company currency A.
            # If you try to pay 12.15A using 0.12B, the computed balance will be 12.00A for the payment instead of 12.15A.
            if edit_mode:
                lines = vals['to_reconcile']

                # Batches are made using the same currency so making 'lines.currency_id' is ok.
                if payment.currency_id != lines.currency_id:
                    liquidity_lines, counterpart_lines, writeoff_lines = payment._seek_for_lines()
                    source_balance = abs(sum(lines.mapped('amount_residual')))
                    if liquidity_lines[0].balance:
                        payment_rate = liquidity_lines[0].amount_currency / liquidity_lines[0].balance
                    else:
                        payment_rate = 0.0
                    source_balance_converted = abs(source_balance) * payment_rate

                    # Translate the balance into the payment currency is order to be able to compare them.
                    # In case in both have the same value (12.15 * 0.01 ~= 0.12 in our example), it means the user
                    # attempt to fully paid the source lines and then, we need to manually fix them to get a perfect
                    # match.
                    payment_balance = abs(sum(counterpart_lines.mapped('balance')))
                    payment_amount_currency = abs(sum(counterpart_lines.mapped('amount_currency')))
                    if not payment.currency_id.is_zero(source_balance_converted - payment_amount_currency):
                        continue

                    delta_balance = source_balance - payment_balance

                    # Balance are already the same.
                    if self.company_currency_id.is_zero(delta_balance):
                        continue

                    # Fix the balance but make sure to peek the liquidity and counterpart lines first.
                    debit_lines = (liquidity_lines + counterpart_lines).filtered('debit')
                    credit_lines = (liquidity_lines + counterpart_lines).filtered('credit')

                    if debit_lines and credit_lines:
                        payment.move_id.write({'line_ids': [
                            (1, debit_lines[0].id, {'debit': debit_lines[0].debit + delta_balance}),
                            (1, credit_lines[0].id, {'credit': credit_lines[0].credit + delta_balance}),
                        ]})
        return payments

    def _post_payments(self, to_process, edit_mode=False):
        """ Post the newly created payments.

        :param to_process:  A list of python dictionary, one for each payment to create, containing:
                            * create_vals:  The values used for the 'create' method.
                            * to_reconcile: The journal items to perform the reconciliation.
                            * batch:        A python dict containing everything you want about the source journal items
                                            to which a payment will be created (see '_get_batches').
        :param edit_mode:   Is the wizard in edition mode.
        """
        payments = self.env['account.payment']
        for vals in to_process:
            payments |= vals['payment']
        payments.action_post()

    def _reconcile_payments(self, to_process, edit_mode=False):
        """ Reconcile the payments.

        :param to_process:  A list of python dictionary, one for each payment to create, containing:
                            * create_vals:  The values used for the 'create' method.
                            * to_reconcile: The journal items to perform the reconciliation.
                            * batch:        A python dict containing everything you want about the source journal items
                                            to which a payment will be created (see '_get_batches').
        :param edit_mode:   Is the wizard in edition mode.
        """
        domain = [
            ('parent_state', '=', 'posted'),
            ('account_type', 'in', ('asset_receivable', 'liability_payable')),
            ('reconciled', '=', False),
        ]
        for vals in to_process:
            payment_lines = vals['payment'].line_ids.filtered_domain(domain)
            lines = vals['to_reconcile']

            for account in payment_lines.account_id:
                (payment_lines + lines)\
                    .filtered_domain([('account_id', '=', account.id), ('reconciled', '=', False)])\
                    .reconcile()

    def _create_payments(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        batches = self._get_batches()
        first_batch_result = batches[0]
        edit_mode = self.can_edit_wizard and (len(first_batch_result['lines']) == 1 or self.group_payment)
        to_process = []

        if edit_mode:
            payment_vals = self._create_payment_vals_from_wizard(first_batch_result)
            to_process.append({
                'create_vals': payment_vals,
                'to_reconcile': first_batch_result['lines'],
                'batch': first_batch_result,
            })
        else:
            # Don't group payments: Create one batch per move.
            if not self.group_payment:
                new_batches = []
                for batch_result in batches:
                    for line in batch_result['lines']:
                        new_batches.append({
                            **batch_result,
                            'payment_values': {
                                **batch_result['payment_values'],
                                'payment_type': 'inbound' if line.balance > 0 else 'outbound'
                            },
                            'lines': line,
                        })
                batches = new_batches

            for batch_result in batches:
                to_process.append({
                    'create_vals': self._create_payment_vals_from_batch(batch_result),
                    'to_reconcile': batch_result['lines'],
                    'batch': batch_result,
                })

        payments = self._init_payments(to_process, edit_mode=edit_mode)
        self._post_payments(to_process, edit_mode=edit_mode)
        self._reconcile_payments(to_process, edit_mode=edit_mode)
        return payments

    def action_create_payments(self):
        payments = self._create_payments()

        if self._context.get('dont_redirect_to_payments'):
            return True

        action = {
            'name': _('Payments'),
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'res_model': 'account.payment',
            'context': {'create': False},
        }
        if len(payments) == 1:
            action.update({
                'view_mode': 'form',
                'res_id': payments.id,
            })
        else:
            action.update({
                'view_mode': 'tree,form',
                'domain': [('id', 'in', payments.ids)],
            })
        return action

here is my code that I wrote trying to intercept the created payment by odoo and make it pass by my approval workflow before posting it
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api, _
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError, UserError
import re
import json
import pickle


class nkap_custom_paiement(models.Model):
    # _inherit = 'account.payment'
    _inherit = ['account.payment']

    to_process_data = fields.Text(string='To Process Data')
    related_payment_id = fields.Many2one('account.payment.register', string='Related Wizard')
    state = fields.Selection([
            ('draft', 'Drafted'),
            ('waiting_approval', 'Waiting Approval'),
            ('approved', 'Approved'),
            ('rejected', 'Rejected'),
            ('posted', 'Posted'),
        ], string="Approval Status")

    DFC_approver_sign = fields.Binary('DFC Signature')
    DG_approver_sign = fields.Binary('DG Signature')
    current_approval = fields.Selection([('1', '1'), ('2', '2'), ('3', '3')], string="Is Current Approver")

    
    def action_submit_for_approval(self):
        company_id=self.env.company
        self.write({'state': 'waiting_approval'})       
        message = "Vous avez un paiement pour la 1ere approbation"
        self.current_approval = '1'
        self.activity_schedule('purchase_order_approval.mail_activity_data_approval', user_id=company_id.po_third_approver_ids.id, note=message)
        self.env['bus.bus']._sendone(company_id.po_third_approver_ids.partner_id, 'simple_notification', {'title': _("Information"), 'message': message})


    def action_DFC_approval(self):
        company_id=self.env.company
        if self.env.user.id in company_id.po_third_approver_ids.ids:
        
            self.current_approval = '2'
            self.write({'state': 'waiting_approval'})
            self.DFC_approver_sign = self.env.user.user_signature
            message = "Vous avez un paiement pour la 2ere approbation "
            self.activity_schedule('purchase_order_approval.mail_activity_data_approval', user_id=company_id.po_DG_approver_ids.id, note=message)
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_("Seul %s peut approver !"% company_id.po_third_approver_ids.id ))

    def action_DG_approval(self):
        company_id=self.env.company
        if self.env.user.id in company_id.po_DG_approver_ids.ids:      

            self.write({'state': 'approved'})
            self.current_approval = '3'
            self.DG_approver_sign = self.env.user.user_signature
            message = "Vous avez un paiement pour la validation"
            self.activity_schedule('purchase_order_approval.mail_activity_data_approval', user_id=company_id.po_fourth_approver_ids.id, note=message)
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_("Seul %s peut approver !"% company_id.po_DG_approver_ids.id ))

    def action_cashier_approval(self):
        company_id=self.env.company
        if self.env.user.id in company_id.po_fourth_approver_ids.ids:
            if self.related_payment_id:
                
                related_payment = self.env['account.payment.register'].browse(related_payment_id)             
                if related_payment.exists():
                    # Call a method on the related payment record
                    related_payment.is_confirmed(payments=self)
                else:
                    _logger.error("Related payment record with ID %s does not exist", self.related_payment_id.id)
            else:
                self.write({'state': 'posted'})
                self.action_post()
                
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_("Seul %s peut approver !"% company_id.po_fourth_approver_ids.id ))
        
    def action_reject(self):
        company_id=self.env.company
        current_approver = None
        if self.current_approval =='1':
            current_approver=company_id.po_third_approver_ids
        elif self.current_approval =='2':
            current_approver=company_id.po_DG_approver_ids
        else:
            raise UserError(_(f"{self.current_approval},{type(self.current_approval)}"))
        if self.env.user.id in current_approver.ids:
            self.write({'state': 'rejected'})
   
        else:
            raise ValidationError(_("Seul %s peut refuser cette DA !" % current_approver.name))

    def rollback(self):
        '''to cancel all the signature already done to false'''
        self.write({
            'DFC_approver_sign': False,
            'DG_approver_sign': False,
            'current_approval': False,
        })
        
        
        

class CustomPaymentRegister(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'account.payment.register'
    # payment_id = fields.Many2one('account.payment', string='Created Payment')
    to_process_data = fields.Binary(string="To Process Data")
    
    def _create_payments(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        batches = self._get_batches()
        first_batch_result = batches[0]
        edit_mode = self.can_edit_wizard and (len(first_batch_result['lines']) == 1 or self.group_payment)
        to_process = []

        if edit_mode:
            payment_vals = self._create_payment_vals_from_wizard(first_batch_result)
            to_process.append({
                'create_vals': payment_vals,
                'to_reconcile': first_batch_result['lines'],
                'batch': first_batch_result,
            })
        else:
            # Don't group payments: Create one batch per move.
            if not self.group_payment:
                new_batches = []
                for batch_result in batches:
                    for line in batch_result['lines']:
                        new_batches.append({
                            **batch_result,
                            'payment_values': {
                                **batch_result['payment_values'],
                                'payment_type': 'inbound' if line.balance > 0 else 'outbound'
                            },
                            'lines': line,
                        })
                batches = new_batches

            for batch_result in batches:
                to_process.append({
                    'create_vals': self._create_payment_vals_from_batch(batch_result),
                    'to_reconcile': batch_result['lines'],
                    'batch': batch_result,
                })

        payments = self._init_payments(to_process, edit_mode=edit_mode)
        self.to_process_data = pickle.dumps(to_process)

        return payments
    
    def _convert_to_process_data(self):
        if self.to_process_data:
            return pickle.loads(self.to_process_data)
        return []
    
    def is_confirmed(self,payments):
        to_process = self._convert_to_process_data()
        if payments.state=='approved' and to_process:
            self._post_payments(self.to_process,edit_mode=False)
            self._reconcile_payments(self.to_process,edit_mode=False)
            if self._context.get('dont_redirect_to_payments'):
              return True
  
            action = {
                'name': _('Payments'),
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
                'res_model': 'account.payment',
                'context': {'create': False},
            }
            if len(payments) == 1:
                action.update({
                    'view_mode': 'form',
                    'res_id': payments.id,
                })
            else:
                action.update({
                    'view_mode': 'tree,form',
                    'domain': [('id', 'in', payments.ids)],
                })
            return action
    def action_create_payments(self):
        payments = self._create_payments()
        payments.related_payment_id=self.id
        
        payments.action_submit_for_approval()


the problem I am enquiring is related to the to_process in the variable "_create_payments" i have tried creating a global variable but a field can not contain a list of dictionaries when i try using pickle.dumps and loads it throw an error because the to_process variable contains some elements like odjects which can not be dumped
Now i have no idea how to solve this problem and make sure Odoo waits for the payment to be validated by the cashier then to process the rest
